# Is there a way to apply select clause with a where clause having condition driven from another select clause?

Tags: sql-server

```
ID     AGENT_CODE     MANAGER_CODE    DESIGNATION            NAME
1      0001           0               GEN MANAGER            STEVE
2      0002           0001            REGIONAL MANAGER       ALBERT
3      0003           0001            REGIONAL MANAGER       JOHN
4      0004           0002            UNIVERSAL TELLER       HENRY
5      0005           0003            UNIVERSAL TELLER       MEVRICK
6      0006           0002            TELLER                 BRINGER
7      0007           0003            TELLER                 ANTONIO
```

It's sample data...

Now I want that if I get an input id, for example I get `ID = 6`

Now I want to select only the connected **parents** and **children** in case of `ID = 6`

`6      0006           0002             TELLER                 BRINGER`

Since I have `Manager ID 0002` it should fetch the result for `0002` in `Agent ID` which is `ID = 2`

`2      0002           0001            REGIONAL MANAGER       ALBERT`

Now I have `Manager ID 0001`, so it should fetch result for `Agent ID 0001`
which is `ID = 1`

`1      0001           0               GEN MANAGER           STEVE`

Now we have `Manager ID` as `0`, hence stop going in the upper direction and now again back to `ID = 6`, where we started.

`6      0006           0002             TELLER                 BRINGER`

Now we will check this row's `Agent ID` in others `Manager ID`... and then select the results and do the same (select `Agent ID` and find in other row's `Manager id`)

Until the bottom end node is fetched.

I think it's enough??

Comment: Provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Just edit your question rather than adding a comment to you own question. Please post some sample data and the results you want. It will make it easy for someone to help with.

Comment: google recursive cte

Comment: @TomC i've provided the data and desired result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways of doing this, but this is the simplest. I am inserting into a temp table variable @result because you want do go both up and down from the target.

First set up your data:

```
declare @t table(ID int, AGENT_CODE varchar(10), MANAGER_CODE varchar(10), DESIGNATION varchar(20), NAME varchar(20))
insert @t values 
 (1, '0001', '0000', 'GEN MANAGER', 'STEVE') 
,(2, '0002', '0001', 'REGIONAL MANAGER', 'ALBERT') 
,(3, '0003', '0001', 'REGIONAL MANAGER', 'JOHN') 
,(4, '0004', '0002', 'UNIVERSAL TELLER', 'HENRY') 
,(5, '0005', '0003', 'UNIVERSAL TELLER', 'MEVRICK') 
,(6, '0006', '0002', 'TELLER', 'BRINGER') 
,(7, '0007', '0003', 'TELLER', 'ANTONIO')

select * from @t
```

Create a table to hold the results, and the target we are looking for

```
declare @result table(ID int, AGENT_CODE varchar(10), MANAGER_CODE varchar(10), DESIGNATION varchar(20), NAME varchar(20))

declare @target int; set @target=6
```

Traverse up the tree

```
;with cte as 
(
    select * from @t where id=@target
    union all
    select t.* from @t t
    join cte on cte.manager_code=t.agent_code
) 
insert @result
select * from cte
```

Traverse down the tree in reverse direction

```
;with cte as 
(
    select * from @t where id=@target
    union all
    select t.* from @t t
    join cte on cte.agent_code=t.manager_code
) 
insert @result
select * from cte
```

Output your result:

```
select distinct * from @result

ID  AGENT_CODE  MANAGER_CODE    DESIGNATION       NAME
1   0001        0000            GEN MANAGER       STEVE
2   0002        0001            REGIONAL MANAGER  ALBERT
6   0006        0002            TELLER            BRINGER
```

Comment: ThankYou soo much It is working jus needed to add 
select distinct * from result order by ID in the end

Answer (score 0):

You could try with a recursive stored procedure (I use two tables for simplicity):

Preparation:

```
CREATE TABLE TEMP
( ID INT
, AGENT_CODE VARCHAR(10)
, MANAGER_CODE VARCHAR(10)
, DESIGNATION VARCHAR(20)
, NAME VARCHAR(20));



CREATE TABLE TEMP_RETURN
( ID INT
, AGENT_CODE VARCHAR(10)
, MANAGER_CODE VARCHAR(10)
, DESIGNATION VARCHAR(20)
, NAME VARCHAR(20));



INSERT INTO TEMP VALUES  
 (1, '0001', '0000', 'GEN MANAGER', 'STEVE') 
,(2, '0002', '0001', 'REGIONAL MANAGER', 'ALBERT') 
,(3, '0003', '0001', 'REGIONAL MANAGER', 'JOHN') 
,(4, '0004', '0002', 'UNIVERSAL TELLER', 'HENRY') 
,(5, '0005', '0003', 'UNIVERSAL TELLER', 'MEVRICK') 
,(6, '0006', '0002', 'TELLER', 'BRINGER') 
,(7, '0007', '0003', 'TELLER', 'ANTONIO');
```

Procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE HIERARCHY @AGENT_CODE AS VARCHAR(10), @MAX_LEVEL AS INTEGER, @CUR_LEVEL AS INTEGER

AS 

BEGIN

DECLARE @VAR_AGENT VARCHAR(10);    
DECLARE @VAR_MANAGER VARCHAR(10);    



SELECT @VAR_AGENT = AGENT_CODE 
     , @VAR_MANAGER = MANAGER_CODE
FROM TEMP
WHERE AGENT_CODE = @AGENT_CODE

IF @VAR_AGENT IS NOT NULL AND @CUR_LEVEL < @MAX_LEVEL
   BEGIN
       INSERT INTO TEMP_RETURN 
       SELECT * FROM TEMP
       WHERE AGENT_CODE = @AGENT_CODE;
       SET @CUR_LEVEL = @CUR_LEVEL + 1;
       EXEC HIERARCHY @VAR_MANAGER, @MAX_LEVEL, @CUR_LEVEL;
   END

END
```

Max level and cur level are used to avoid infinite loops in case of cycles on the table

Call and show data:

```
DELETE
FROM TEMP_RETURN;


EXEC HIERARCHY @AGENT_CODE='0006', @CUR_LEVEL = 0, @MAX_LEVEL = 100;

SELECT *
FROM TEMP_RETURN
ORDER BY AGENT_CODE;
```

Output:

```
1   0001    0000    GEN MANAGER STEVE
2   0002    0001    REGIONAL MANAGER    ALBERT
6   0006    0002    TELLER  BRINGER
```

Hope it helps :-)